# Edge detection overlay with lines

Tags: ios, core-image, metal, edge-detection

I need to overlay the edges detected in live video preview with a color of my choice (as is done in Lightroom CC app when you adjust focus). What's the easiest way to draw those lines in real time using Metal or CoreImage? I can use Sobel edge detection to detect the edges using Metal Performance Shader but not sure how to overlay the edges with a color of my choice.

Comment: I think you've already found something - there are several examples out there on using Sobel and outputting in the color of your choice... if you are having an issue there, can you supply specifics? If the issue is performance, again, can you supply specifics? What are you doing right now? And what is the issue with what you are doing?

Comment: Can you please point me to the example where they use Sobel and output the color? I do not know how to do this using Metal or CoreImage or OpenGLES.

Comment: The basic idea may be to do convolution of the image with Sobel kernel and use a threshold to output a color. However this is just an idea and I guess there may be much better & precise implementations. Only thing is I am unable to search it on internet, may be lack of proper keywords!

Comment: I understand. Here's three links that should help you with doing convolution and Sobel. (1) *THE* resource as far as I'm concerned - https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Filterpedia be careful, it's Swift 2. If you want a deeper explanation, check out his book *CoreImage for Swift*. (2) The Swift 3 fork I use (all but the Metal filters I've easily upgraded to Swift 4) https://github.com/Norod/Filterpedia Both of these pass an array into `CIConvolution5X5`. If you know how to write your own kernel, here's a 3x3 matrix to use http://coding-experiments.blogspot.com.au/2010/07/convolution.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is a edge detect shader for metal

```
kernel void edge_detect(texture2d<half, access::read>  inTexture  [[ texture(0) ]],
                        texture2d<half, access::write> outTexture [[ texture(1) ]],
                        uint2                          gid        [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {
    constexpr int kernel_size = 3;
    constexpr int radius = kernel_size / 2;
    
    half3x3 horizontal_kernel = half3x3(-1./8., -1./8., -1./8.,
                                        -1./8.,  1.,    -1./8.,
                                        -1./8., -1./8., -1./8.);
    half3x3 vertical_kernel = half3x3(-1./8., -1./8., -1./8.,
                                      -1./8.,  1.,    -1./8.,
                                      -1./8., -1./8., -1./8.);
    
    half3 result_horizontal(0,0,0);
    half3 result_vertical(0,0,0);
    for(int j = 0; j <= kernel_size - 1; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= kernel_size - 1; i++) {
            uint2 texture_index(gid.x + (i - radius), gid.y + (j - radius));
            result_horizontal += horizontal_kernel[i][j] * inTexture.read(texture_index).rgb;
            result_vertical += vertical_kernel[i][j] * inTexture.read(texture_index).rgb;
        }
    }
    
    half3 bt601 = half3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114);
    half gray_horizontal = dot(result_horizontal.rgb, bt601);
    half gray_vertical = dot(result_vertical.rgb, bt601);
    half magnitude = length(half2(gray_horizontal, gray_vertical));
    
    outTexture.write(half4(half3(magnitude), 1), gid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but if anyone still needs it I figured it out just now. It's very easy to find an edge detection shader, but not easy to figure out how to change the color of the detected edges, especially if you are new to this. Here is my kernel:

```
typedef struct {
    simd_float3 rgb;
} AppliedColor;

kernel void edgeEffect(texture2d<half, access::read>  inputTexture  [[ texture(0) ]],
                       texture2d<half, access::read_write> outputTexture [[ texture(1) ]],
                       constant float &edgeStrength [[ buffer(0) ]],
                       constant AppliedColor &newColor [[ buffer(1) ]],
                       uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    
    
    constexpr int kernelSize = 3;
    constexpr int radius = kernelSize / 2;
    
    half3x3 horizontalKernel = half3x3(-1, -2, -1,
                                       0, 0, 0,
                                       1, 2, 1);
    
    half3x3 verticalKernel = half3x3(1, 0, -1,
                                     2, 0, -2,
                                     1, 0, -1);
    
    half3 horizontalResult(0, 0, 0);
    half3 verticalResult(0, 0, 0);
    
    for(int j = 0; j <= kernelSize - 1; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= kernelSize - 1; i++) {
            uint2 textureIndex(gid.x + (i - radius), gid.y + (j - radius));
            horizontalResult += horizontalKernel[i][j] * inputTexture.read(textureIndex).rgb;
            verticalResult += verticalKernel[i][j] * inputTexture.read(textureIndex).rgb;
        }
    }
    
    half horizontalWhite = dot(horizontalResult.rgb, half3(1.0));
    half verticalWhite = dot(verticalResult.rgb, half3(1.0));
    
    half magnitude = length(half2(horizontalWhite, verticalWhite)) * edgeStrength;
    
    outputTexture.write(half4(half3(newColor.rgb * magnitude), 1), gid);

}//edgeEffect
```

This is using Sobel kernels to calculate the derivatives.